# jQuery ajax doesn't work on ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this call:

```
$.ajax({dataType: "json",
        url: '<url_here>',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
});
```

That works on every browser ou there... except on IE :( (I'm testing version 8)
The success function is never called so it looks like the function (.ajax) isn't executed right (or at all). Anyone know anything about jquery ajax on ie 8?

Comment: are you using console.log somewhere ?

Comment: You should also provide an `error` callback to see if there are any errors returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this ones are always good, where one answer to himself :)

The problem was that looks like IE doesn't parse the headers from the ajax'ed site. So as this was a cross domain request, it was allowing it to get through. So, I had to activate "Access data sources across domain" on IE security settings. On other browsers, just adding the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * would allow for cross site scripting, just not on IE.

One other thing I had to add to the script was:
jQuery.support.cors = true;

or I would get "No transport available"

Answer (score 0):

This is because, my default, IE8 doesn't support JSON. You need to include the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library in your project.

Comment: do i only need json2 ou all the *.js files? 'cause only with json2.js it doesn't work :(

Comment: It should be just json2.js that you need to include. In IE8, press F12 and open up the Developer Toolbar, then look in Console. You should see your exact error there.